# How to print list using hierarchical data structure?

Tags: php, list, hierarchy

When I run this code:

```
foreach ($tree as $node) {
    echo str_repeat(' ', $node->tree_depth * 4) . $node->id . PHP_EOL;
}
```

I get well formatted text like:

```
Food
 Fruit
   Red
     Cherry
     Strawberry
               Cool
               Not cool
   Yellow
     Banana
 Meat
   Beef
   Pork
```

But I want to create a list with `<ul><li>...`:

I tried with:

```
echo '<ul>';
$prev_depth = 0;
foreach($table->fetchTree() as $row) {
    if ($row->tree_depth > $prev_depth) {
        echo '<li><ul>';
    } else if ($row->tree_depth < $prev_depth) {
        echo '</li></ul>';
    }
    echo '<li>' . $row->name . '</li>';
    $prev_depth = $row->tree_depth;
}
echo '</ul>';
```

But I have some extra ul tags and so on.  I lost 2 days on this so if you can help me please post here...

Comment: We would probably need a small dataset.

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318488/build-hierarchical-html-tags-in-php-from-flat-data?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this algorithm:

```
$tree = array(
    array('Food', 0),
    array('Fruit', 1),
    array('Red', 2),
    array('Cherry', 3),
    array('Strawberry', 3),
    array('Cool', 4),
    array('Not cool', 4),
    array('Yellow', 2),
    array('Banana', 3),
    array('Meat', 0),
    array('Beef', 1),
    array('Pork', 1),
);

$depth = -1;
$flag = false;
foreach ($tree as $row) {
    while ($row[1] > $depth) {
        echo "<ul>\n", "<li>";
        $flag = false;
        $depth++;
    }
    while ($row[1] < $depth) {
        echo "</li>\n", "</ul>\n";
        $depth--;
    }
    if ($flag) {
        echo "</li>\n", "<li>";
        $flag = false;
    }
    echo $row[0];
    $flag = true;
}
while ($depth-- > -1) {
    echo "</li>\n", "</ul>\n";
}
```

Here you just need to replace `$tree` by `$table->fetchTree()`, `$row[0]` by `$row->name` and `$row[1]` by `$row->tree_depth`.

Comment: Gumbo, believed or not I found a problem with your algorithm but unfortunately, I am not able to solve it, problem is that your algorithm isn't generating valid ul li structure and u have some extra non necessary tags, can u solve it !?

Comment: I don’t see any errors. Do you have an example where the output is invalid?

Comment: Yes I do actually, how do u want me to send it!? Also I can send u an email if u want. Here is the output, it looks ok in browser but if u analyze the source u will see the problem http://jsbin.com/oliya

Comment: There is somewhere a `</l>` instead of a `</li>` in your code. But mine is correct.

Comment: Then where does the `</l>` in this line come from? See http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com%2Foliya&ss=1#line-53

Comment: I am sorry, but thats irrelevant, I probably deleted somehow that one line when I was posting and editing the code on js bin. But that's not the php output take a look at new version with closed l tag http://jsbin.com/icela

Comment: Ah, I got it. I think I found the error. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Well Gumbo u are one amazing dude :D Tell me are u available for some freelance work and/or cooperation and how can I contact u!?

Comment: Sorry I didn't saw that u edited the code! But I must tell u that your code is working horrible now :( It ain't creating what it should be creating! Now each now is child of first printed row :D

Comment: It isn't try it and u will see what am I talking about! I can send my complex array if u want. But your code was working in first place and everything was fine except few not necessary tags! Now it simply ain't working!

Comment: Did you consider that my depth count begins with 0 as the first level?

Comment: Yes I did, and I was changing the deep but without results. Can u tell me one thing, how I can get this output as string!? Not to echo it so I can remove the extra tags with some classic function!?

Comment: Replace the `echo` by `$str.=` and the `,` inside the `echo` by `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
<?php
echo "<ul>\n";

$tree = array(
    array('Food', 0),
    array('Fruit', 1),
    array('Red', 5),
    array('Cherry', 3),
    array('Strawberry', 3),
    array('Cool', 4),
    array('Not cool', 4),
    array('Yellow', 2),
    array('Banana', 3),
    array('Meat', 0),
    array('Beef', 4),
    array('Pork', 2),
);

$depth = 0;

foreach ($tree as $node) {
  if ($node[1] > $depth)
    echo str_repeat("<ul>\n", $node[1] - $depth);
  if ($node[1] < $depth)
    echo str_repeat("</ul>\n", $depth - $node[1]);
  $depth = $node[1];

  echo "<li>" .  $node[0] . "\n";
}
echo str_repeat("</ul>\n", $depth+1);
?>
```

I've updated it to output fewer `<li>` tags, thereby reducing the number of bullets. But on the other hand, this will generate HTML that wont validate since a jump of more than one level will result in a `<ul><ul>` being generated.

Comment: Dude this is giving me the pretty much the same output as code that I posted in my question, so this isn't a solution...

Comment: It was quite hard to see what you were really asking... I thought your problem was the jumps in more than one level, which my code handles.

Comment: I think, that my question maybe isn't perfectly clear, but the code which I posted is clear like milk :D
Anyway thank you for help, I appreciate it, really...

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear that!